# How to print 10 numbers per line using Math.random() in java?

Tags: java, arrays, math

I want to basically output 10 numbers per line separated by comma from 0 up to 100 (inclusively). This has to be done only using the Math.random() method, and no other methods at all. Also, I need to put it in an array. This is what I tried so far:

```
// Create class and method
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Assign a int array and set the limit to 100
int[] numbers = new int[100];

// Create a for loop to output numbers upto 100
  for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    // Use Math.random() to output random integers, and use typecasting to convert double into int
    numbers[x] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    System.out.print(numbers[x]+" ,");
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

My Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz2zz.png)

Comment: What output are you getting, then? And is there any need for the array? You can just directly print a random number instead of storing it in `numbers[x]`

Comment: Why do you need the array for this task?  You could generate the 10 random numbers and just print them.  Also, `(int)(Math.random()*100)` creates numbers in range `[0..99]` (excluding 100)

Comment: yes but i want it including and with arrays

Comment: Add a call to `System.out.println()` when you exit the inner loop.

Comment: that is the whole point of task is to use arrays

Comment: Your inner loop is overriding `numbers[x]` 10 times rather than adding them to the array in a new position.

Comment: @Abra, how? could you show me?

Comment: Why do you need to put the numbers into an array?

Comment: I just would have used a single array. Put ``if ((x % 10) == 0) {System.out.println();} else {System.out.print(", ");}`` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create class and method
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = new int[100];

    for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
        numbers[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
        if(((x+1)%10) == 0){
          System.out.println(numbers[x]);
        }else{
          System.out.print(numbers[x] + " ,");
        } 
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested.

```java
int[] numbers = new int[100];

// Create a for loop to output numbers upto 100
int i = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    // Use Math.random() to output random integers, and use typecasting to convert
    // double into int
    numbers[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    System.out.print(numbers[x] + " ,");
    i++;
    if (i == 10) {
        System.out.println();
        i = 0;
    }
}
```